# iPhone Address Book - Always Pulls from Default Group

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

I'm rolling my own PeoplePicker, using the following code to get all my contacts:

```
ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(ab);    
NSArray *allContacts = (NSArray *) ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(ab, source, ABPersonGetSortOrdering());
```

It's worked fine during development, but now we're in beta, and a user complained that when they went to choose a contact in my app, the list they were given to choose from was a small subset of all their contacts in their phone.

We pinned it down to the fact that it was actually just displaying one of their groups.

A while later, I realized you can set your default group in Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Contacts > Default Group

If a user has a specific group selected, then just that group displays in my app.

I think this is because I'm using `ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource` to get all the contacts.

How can I grab all a user's contacts without regard to the default source?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
for( int i=0;i< nPeople;i++)
{
        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);
        CFStringRef firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        .....
        and so on
}
```